# RegEdit Error "Cannot Find the File Specified" Accessing Key

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-registry

I have a corrupted install of Symantec Endpoint Protection on one of my Windows Server 2012R2 servers and I am trying to manually remove the software (following Symantec's guide).  Two of the keys (HKLM\Software\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\CurrentVersion and HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\CurrentVersion) I need to delete are giving me the following error as soon as I try and access either key:

```
CurrentVersion cannot be opened.
An error is preventing this key from being opened.
Details: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried removing it in safe mode.  I have tried using the RegDelNull utility from SysInternals.  I have tried deleting it from the command line (REG /DELETE) and I have tried deleting the parent key.  None of these things worked.  It is not a permission issue because if I try and go in to the permissions for this key I just get a red X and the message "The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed."

How can I remove these keys?

Comment: Taking it literally, are the registry files there?  They should be under C:\Windows\System32\config: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724877(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, the HKLM\Software hive exists because I have no problems with the parent nodes of CurrentVersion.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on my Windows 7 box. I eventually figured out that the key was a broken symbolic link. The built-in `regedit` tool does not seem to properly support these, and acts as described when trying to access such a key.

I managed to delete the broken symbolic link using https://github.com/tenox7/regln like this:

```
C:\Users\Zero3\Desktop>regln-x64.exe -d "\Registry\User\S-1-5-21-1688150413-3759
594893-2435602081-1000\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extension
s\Approved"
```

You will need to adapt the path to your use case, of course.

(For reference, I noted that a similar issue was posted here: https://superuser.com/questions/1039043/impossible-to-remove-registry-key)